# Using third party UI libraries with TornadoFX

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I want to use JFoenix library (or other UI libraries) with TornadoFX. Is there a tutorial how to use third party components with type-save builders in TornadoFX?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The type safe builders operate on the instances of the nodes you create, so you can create a custom node and either do `children.add(myCustomComponent)` or even `this += myCustomComponent` or `add(myCustomComponent)` inside of a builder. They all do the same - add the custom component to the children list of the node you called `add` on.

```
hbox {
    label("Builders + custom components")
    val myCustomComponent = SomeCustomComponent()
    // Add to HBox
    add(myCustomComponent)
}
```

If you want to take the integration one step further, you can add builder functions for the custom components so you can write `hbox { myCustomComponent { ... } }`. For more information about how to add builders, check out the source code.

Comment: Thank you for fast answer. You make a great job, and always give help to the others, this is impressive.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. We have so many people in our community that are helping out both here and on Slack, so it should always be easy to get answers to TornadoFX related questions :)